# odoo 8 Button Logic

Tags: button, methods, triggers, odoo

i'm new with Odoo 8. I added a Button in my module (inherit sale order) to be able to execute the method calkulateEKNew. The function is calling how it should be, but it looks like that the button is doing more stuff in the background. After clicking the button it saves the sale order and calls the method calkulateEKNew. 
Is it possible to trigger this button or to find the logic behind the button ?

Nice regards

Comment: This is the xml:    <xpath expr='//field[@name="order_line"]' position="before">
                    <group>
                        <button string="Aktualisieren" type="object" name="calkulateEkNew"
                                class="oe_highlight"/>
         </group>
</xpath>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include further information in a properly formatted way.

Comment: The logic behing the button? It is javascript and it is complicated. After clicking the button your object will be saved and new (changed) values will be shown on your form.  What do ya wanna to achive?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I dont want to click the button. Is it possible to implement this in my code ? To trigger the Button or execute the Button Method from a @api.onchange . So i dont have to click the Button each time.

Comment: How can i find out which javascript Function i have to call ?

Comment: Is it not possible to call the js function which the button is using ? @Naveen I have to use odoo 8

Comment: Try to use the stable version like odoo 10 or 11. Odoo 11 is much shrinked in code and functionality compared to the previous versions

Answer (score 1):

Buttons are available to execute python methods on the Odoo server.
If you want to execute JavaScript code, you'll have to add a (client-side) widget, possibly a template and a JavaScript file to your module.

This URL points to further information about simple widgets:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/web.html#widgets-basics

Comment: Thank you!!! But how can i find out which js function this button calls ?

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to set the button as required if a field in sale oder line changes ? So that the user has to click the button

Comment: For the first question: you can register a click handler. For details,  please refer to that documentation.

Comment: for the second question: please add more context to describe what you mean by a "mandatory button". It may be better to ask this as a separate question.

Comment: I would like to force the user to click this button, if for example the price unit field in sale order line is changing. Maybe you have a idea how i could make it. Is this possible ?

Comment: Why would you force a user to do this? If something needs to happen automatically, do an "@onchange". If the user needs to conform something, propose the whole thing in a popup dialog. If you need to validate something, add a "@constraint". Many ways ... but I don't see how you can force somebody to click a button.

Comment: yes and this is my problem. I just need the method which the button is calling. So i could call it from a @onchange automatically. But i didnt find anything in the documentation how to find the method behind the button with a click handler.

Comment: The onchange method is a server-side mechanism to call (python) code whenever a value changes in the form. There is no automatic way to call a client-side (JavaScript) method. You should be able to do this with plain JavaScript framework methods. However, I'm pretty sure that this is not a good idea. Business logic should be entirely server-side, coded in Python. In particular to enforce data consistency.